# How to enable multi-touch on touchscreen laptop?

Tags: laptop, asus-laptop, touchscreen, asus

I have Windows 11 running on Asus Vivobook. I downloaded Bluestacks Emulator to play PUB-G but while playing my device is not receiving multiple touches like running and shooting simultaneously. How to enable multi-touch on touchscreen laptop?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-touch

[Click here to check out my laptop screen image. You can clearly see that it supports multi-touch but I don't know why does it not respond to those touches.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ky2Di.jpg)

Comment: Does multi-touch work in Windows? If the hardware doesn't support it there's nothing to "enable", you just can't. But if the hardware supports it, it'll work in the OS and your issue is in Bluestacks.

Comment: @music2myear I have added an image of my laptop screen. Please check it.

Comment: Then your issue is in Bluestacks and whatever driver it uses for multi-touch. Is this issue only happening in that one app/game?